# Why am I getting this UnicodeDecodeError during a Mysql SELECT query?

Tags: python, mysql, windows, codec

I'm running a pretty basic script that is querying a MySQL table, but I'm running into an error that I can't find online. I see a lot of charmap/codec related issues online, but all have to do with reading text or data.

This error is happening when I attempt a MySQL SELECT query, or at least I think it is.

Does anyone know why Python would error on this?

[image]

My code reads like this:

[image]

Line 188 is where the error occurs.

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the following answer:
[Encoding Issue - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662951/python-unicode-encoding-issue)

Adding the extra parameters while creating connection should resolve your issue.

```
con = mdb.connect('loclhost', 'root', '', 'mydb', use_unicode=True, charset='utf8')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`alt` column contains [`OSC` control character (0x9d)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+009D). Seems to be a data problem. You could try replacing the character to verify that's the issue but the long term solution should be to not allow those character in a string, convert them to html entities, or specify a connection character set.

```
SELECT id, REPLACE(alt, UNHEX('9D'), '&#157;') ...
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640513/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9d-in-position-x-charac).